# Add a column from a function of 2 other columns in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have two columns in a data frame `df` in PySpark:

```
| features |  center  |
+----------+----------+
| [0,1,0]  | [1.5,2,1]|
| [5,7,6]  | [10,7,7] |
```

I want to create a function which calculates the Euclidean distance between `df['features']` and `df['center']` and map it to a new column in df, `distance`.

Let's say our function looks like the following:

```py
@udf
def dist(feat, cent):
    return np.linalg.norm(feat-cent)
```

How would I actually apply this to do what I want it to do? I was trying things like

```py
df.withColumn("distance", dist(col("features"), col("center"))).show()
```

but that gives me the following error:

> rg.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 869.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 869.0 (TID 26423) (10.50.91.134 executor 35): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)

I am really struggling with understanding how to do basic Python mappings in a Spark context, so I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have truly chosen a difficult topic. In Spark, 95%+ of things can be done without python UDFs. You should always try to find a way not to create a UDF.

I've attempted your UDF, I got the same error, and I cannot really tell, why. I think there's something with data types, as you pass Spark array into a function which expects numpy data types. I really can't tell much more...

For Euclidian distance, it's possible to calculate it in Spark. Not an easy one, though.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([0, 1, 0], [1.5, 2., 1.]),
     ([5, 7, 6], [10., 7., 7.])],
    ['features', 'center'])

distance = F.aggregate(
    F.transform(
        F.arrays_zip('features', 'center'),
        lambda x: (x['features'] - x['center'])**2
    ),
    F.lit(0.0),
    lambda acc, x: acc + x,
    lambda x: x**.5
)
df = df.withColumn('distance', distance)

df.show()
# +---------+----------------+------------------+
# | features|          center|          distance|
# +---------+----------------+------------------+
# |[0, 1, 0]| [1.5, 2.0, 1.0]|2.0615528128088303|
# |[5, 7, 6]|[10.0, 7.0, 7.0]|5.0990195135927845|
# +---------+----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: As a spatial scientist I encourage use scipy or sklearn to compute euclidean distances. Whereas this method works it does not consider earth curvature and other imperatives. Increase the span of coordinates and you see huge differences. Computationally this works , spatially it is prone to error. Good answer though

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import paired_distances
```

Alter dfs schema to accommodate the dist column

```
sch= df.withColumn('dist', lit(90.087654623)).schema
```

Create pandas udf that claculates distance

```
def euclidean_dist(iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    for pdf in iterator:
           
      yield pdf.assign(dist=paired_distances(pdf['features'].to_list(),pdf['center'].to_list()))

df.mapInPandas(euclidean_dist, schema=sch).show()
```

Solution

```
+---------+----------------+------------------+
| features|          center|              dist|
+---------+----------------+------------------+
|[0, 1, 0]| [1.5, 2.0, 1.0]|2.0615528128088303|
|[5, 7, 6]|[10.0, 7.0, 7.0]|5.0990195135927845|
+---------+----------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the distance using only PySpark and spark sql APIs:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('distance', f.sqrt(f.expr('aggregate(transform(features, (element, idx) -> pow(element - element_at(center, idx + 1), 2)), cast(0 as double), (acc, val) -> acc + val)')))
)
```